# Formula to calculate pay when the first hour worked is a different rate, with breaks

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to create invoices for publicly-funded interpreters. They are paid $X for the first hour (or fraction thereof) they work on a given case, and then $Y (which is less) for each additional hour (or fraction thereof). I would modify an overtime formula, but there is another common scenario in which the interpreter works, on one day, e.g., 90 minutes with Client A, then 15 minutes with Client B, then another 120 minutes with Client A. Their invoice for Client A for that day would be 60 minutes at $X, and 30 + 120 minutes at $Y. Then if they worked with Client A again the next day, again the first hour would be paid at $X

Ideally there would be two rows per day worked (time worked @ $X and time worked @ $Y), and each invoice would cover several meetings over as much as a year (if that's relevant), and it would be extra amazing if it was also easy to calculate the total number of hours at $X and at $Y covered by the invoice (because of the different ways the information has to be entered into the public funder's billing portal).

I have access to Excel if there is a way that is only supported by Excel, but I'd rather use sheets.

Comment: Hello! Are you still working on it?

Comment: Yes, I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Could you share a sketch of how you'd like it to appear?? Would it be one row per day?, One row per client per day?

Comment: Okay, I've tried to write out an explanation but it isn't really making sense. Here's an example of what I have now, where I have to split things up manually: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AMkGW3XGASzDfghpv4tEdR4bmESaGwVJYIZ0SVR4YgM/edit?usp=sharing